# Seeking Ubuntu Version Compatibility Resource

Tags: installation

I have an older mac power pc g4 and I would like to know where I can find out which versions of ubuntu will run on it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a PowerPC version of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (supported until April 2017) located here http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.3/release/ .

You can also get 13.04 (supported until January 2014) from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/) instead if you want the latest version.

Use Ctrl+F to search for `powerpc.iso` and download the one with `desktop` in the name which ends with `.iso`.

Follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Installation) for burning and installing it.

Note: This is **not** officially supported by Canonical and is a community port.